# Install Firefox addon in chroot environment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

My goal is to install some Firefox addon inside some chroot environment.
I see 2 options here: either run firefox with X from within the chroot and install the addons or put all the files where they need to be.

For the first option I did set the DISPLAY variable and allowed connection from localhost with xhost +local. I can now run graphical software like the calculator.. Bur when I try to run firefox I get some errors:

```
dbus-laucnh terminated abnormally with the following error: EOF in dbus-laucnh reading address from bus daemon
```

So I tried the second option and placed the .xpi file in .mozilla/extensions but this has no effect

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message you might wanna try bind-mounting your Dbus sockets inside the chroot in order to communicate with the host.